# Name for this type of model?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am looking at a process with 2 distinct states, call them A and B. However, the number of the next state depends on the number of the current state, which can be chosen.

So for example, if $|A|_t$ = number of things in state A at time t, and $|B|_t$ = number of things in state B at time t, then in the next state ($t+1$), the state can be either:

$ |A|_{t+1} = |A|_t + |B|_t$, $|B|_{t+1} = |B|_t$

or

$ |A|_{t+1} = |A|_t$, $|B|_{t+1} = |A|_t + |B|_t$

Is there a name for this type of process? I know I have worked on Markov chains with bacteria models (theoretical) in stochastic processes courses, but I am trying to figure out if this would constitute a specific kind of Markov model (or if there is a name for it).

I just don't seem to remember the name of this type of process: I know there are birth-death processes, and perhaps some other stochastic processes with descriptive names that skip my mind at the moment.

Comment: If you view the pair $(|A|_t, |B|_t)$ as a state, then this is certainly a Markov chain. I am not sure if there is a name for this particular model. (You also have not specified the probability distributions.) It is reminiscent of an urn model, but I may be wrong.

Comment: This certainly sounds like an interesting model, e.g. even in the simplest case where at each time step, you pick which update equation to use $\sim Bernoulli(p)$.  What is this inspired by?